# Equation of lines

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

What is the distance between the line with Cartesian equation x-4 = y-4 = z and the line with Cartesian equation x-3=y-4 = z-1?

Comment: "Does this imply its correct"- what do you mean by "correct"? Is this a question from your book? If yes, please include that question as well.

Comment: Yeah ,it asks if its true or false statement

Comment: Please include that in your question (that the book is asking whether the statement is true or false).

Comment: What do you know about the dot product of two orthogonal vectors?

Comment: It is equal to zero

Comment: You should find the direct vector of both lines, and use the dot product.

Comment: What do you mean by direct vector please!?